# How to implement color correction based on known background color?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I have a dataset of face images which were captured with a uniform gray background. Because of the lighting variations during collection, the images no longer have same color tone. The backgrounds color looks different for all the images.
I want to find the exact skin color and wanted to implement color correction using the fact that all images had uniform gray background. How can I implement this using python?

Comment: do you want to correct only the face color or the hair color too?

Comment: in your question you say that the backgrounds differs from image to image, but in header you state that the background is known?

Comment: Ground truth background is RGB 119,119,199 but the images appear to have different shades of gray because of the variable  lighting conditions.

Comment: I wanted to color correct the whole image including face and hair. Such that corrected background pixels are RGB (119,119,119)

Comment: What makes the background color change exactly ?

Comment: I don't see any images.

Comment: Here are some sample images:
https://pasteboard.co/J5csbEe.png

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your pixels are converted to floats in the range 0,0,0 (black) to 1,1,1 (white). You have a vector in 3D (RGB) space from the picture background to the known value.  To correct, calculate a correction by multiplying each component by the magnitude of the correction needed.  So if you have dR, dG, dB as the differences, all between 0.0 and 1.0, and R,G,B is a pixel, Rnew = R * (1.0 + dR) clipping max at 1.0.  This will keep black pixels black.